# Is anything wrong with my hyperledger network setup in my local machine?

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger

As guide of https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/master/docs/Setup/Network-setup.md

In my command 1:
docker run --rm -it -e CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=http://172.17.0.1:2375 -e CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL=DEBUG -e CORE_PEER_ID=vp0 -e CORE_PEER_ADDRESSAUTODETECT=true hyperledger/fabric-peer peer node start
[image]

In my command 2:
docker run --rm -it -e CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=http://172.17.0.1:2375 -e CORE_PEER_ID=vp1 -e CORE_PEER_ADDRESSAUTODETECT=true -e CORE_PEER_DISCOVERY_ROOTNODE=172.17.0.2:30303 hyperledger/fabric-peer peer node start

[image]

And I want to check my network status, "./peer node status" failed?
[image]

How can I check the network status in local machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The  `./peer node status` tries to connect to peer on host machine, but your network is started in docker container. 
You can check the status using:

```
 “CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=172.17.0.2:30303 ./peer node status"
```